# Can i hit an endpoint and get/echo the <body>?

Tags: php

I currently don't even know what exactly to search, don't know if that procedure has a name or something, that's why i decided to post a question.

For example, when i hit mysite/test.php i want that php to make a request to another .php on another server and get all the html contents of that page and echo it in test.php, is that even possible?

Let's suppose test.php is that php file which makes a request to take_me.php .

take_me.php could have just an echo or it could be a full content page.

Can i have the content of take_me.php shown in test.php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `file_get_contents` and `echo` to screen like below:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

if (isset($html)) {

    echo $html;

}
```

You may have issue with images rendering correctly etc... due to paths but it will work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php